# Implicit mimic of click

Tags: javascript

In the next lines I replace word 'first' with word 'second' and then the user may click on word 'second'. I wonder if there is some way to enter the mimic of click inside `<span onclick="myFunction()">second</span>` so as the user not to have to click on word 'second'. It has to run instantly. Please keep in mind that I am not interested just in running 'myFunction' but mimicing **implicitely** the click.

```
<div id = 'FirstSentence'>This is the first sentence</div>
<div id = 'SecondSentence'></div>
<div id = 'itWorked'></div>

<script>
    jSentence = document.getElementById('FirstSentence').innerHTML
    jSentence = jSentence.replace('first', `<span onclick="myFunction()">second</span>`)
    document.getElementById('SecondSentence').innerHTML = jSentence

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('itWorked').innerHTML = 'it worked !!!';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("span").textContent.includes("second").click();`

Comment: Dear Marcus, did you test it ? It worked for me as document.querySelector("span").click(); Please make it an answer, since it is a clever idea.

Comment: @Apostolos is the below answer is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to call click function on the element, please see the example below.

```js
jSentence = document.getElementById('FirstSentence').innerHTML
    jSentence = jSentence.replace('first', `<span onclick="myFunction()">second</span>`)
    document.getElementById('SecondSentence').innerHTML = jSentence

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('itWorked').innerHTML = 'it worked !!!';
    }
    
     document.getElementById('SecondSentence').querySelector('span').click();
```

```html
<div id = 'FirstSentence'>This is the first sentence</div>
<div id = 'SecondSentence'></div>
<div id = 'itWorked'></div>
```

Comment: Bravo !!! it works fine since it implicits refers to span. Thank you very much !!!